# Why I can see project in Google Cloud Platform which I didn't created?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On resources pending deletion page in Google Cloud Platform Console I can see project which I didn't created.

```
Name: Global Site Operations 602748
ID: projects/tamzidms-github-io
```

[image]
Can someone explain this or does someone else experience similar issue?

Comment: We would need more information. Do you have an organization? If yes, and you have the correct roles, you can see all projects beneath the organization level. To obtain access to a project is as simple as adding your email address to my project. Google has good documentation on IAM plus there are good videos on YouTube.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have an organization, it is my solo account. Do you suggest someone could add me to his project?

Comment: Yes, a Project member with the correct roles can add any email address to their project. To see the projects that you can access `gcloud projects list`. This does not make you responsible for the project.

Comment: @JohnHanley what if there is no any other project member, and this is a simple account I created recently with no touching at all.

Comment: @Abraham - How does your comment apply to the question asked?

Comment: @JohnHanley I got the same projects in my cloud console and I never created them. and I have nobody related to this account, I even created the gmail account recently and never told anyone about it.

but yet, I found 3 projects that I have never seen before, even worse, one had billing enabled.

Comment: @Abraham - I cannot answer. The project IDs are interesting in that these appear to be Google created project IDs. Are the Project IDs (not names) exactly the same? I have dozens of projects, and I have never seen this. Do you see anything in Cloud Logging under Audited Resource?

Comment: @JohnHanley this are the projects on my account:https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXvpw.png. They all seem too meaningful to believe they are generated by google.


All the first 3 in the image are projects I haven't created.

Comment: @Abraham - Your comment was that you had the "same" projects. Those Project IDs do not have numbers at the end, which indicates they were either created a long time ago, or those are GCP names. Your Project IDs look very much like you created them. The Cloud Logging audit logs will tell you who (IAM Identity) created your projects.

Comment: I've never created those projects. It's the project IDs as you stated that made me really suspicious and changed my password. I disabled billing on those projects and immediately deleted them. I can't see the audit log since they're deleted. But I'm dead sure I never created those projects, I even had searched them on google to see If anyone had same thing happen before. I've even never thought of those words on the Project ID before. and the number `-308710` at the end made me even more suspicious. Incase it's an ID by the creator, for many victims, operating like those crypto mining malware.